# Using QScrollArea and QLabel to show image from stream

Tags: multithreading, qt

Recently, I'm working on a frame grabber application. In order to display the image grabbed by the camera with vertical and horizontal scroll bar, I use QScollArea and QLabel. The code is as follow:

https://gist.github.com/tianshilei1992/775234959c6bdbdd635b

The code could work fine if it only displays a image statically. The grabber will call the callback function as long as it receives data. Perhaps due to the reason that the frame rate is too high, up to 400 fps, if I drag the scrollbar when the grabber is working, the application will crash. I guess this is because when I drag the scrollbar, the application will re-paint the image, but since the callback function is too fast, the application found that the image it wants to re-paint has been replaced by the new one, so it crashes. The code of this project could be found at https://github.com/tianshilei1992/CameraGrabber/blob/master/mainwindow.cpp Line 346 to 364 register the asynchronous service. The callback function is from line 508 to 515.

Is there any solutions for this issue?

Comment: Maybe you can try use slot as callback function.

Comment: Yes! I defined a new signal and a slot function to do the refreshing, it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I just defined a new signal and slot function to do the refreshing, emit REFRESHING in the callback function. Done!

https://gist.github.com/tianshilei1992/fd76520532127deb28de